# Get all files named month by month

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

i have system of log that write logs each day with this format: "stat.dat_20220901_235900.txt","stat.dat_20220902_235900.txt",...
i need to get content of all files by month and create file named like "September" with all content of daily.

```
$Date= -Format("MMddyyyy_hhmmss")
$path="C:\Users\**\**\**\**\stat.dat_$Date"
$CharArray =Get-Content -Path $path
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i need to a monthly file month.txt with data of each day by month

Comment: like s content of this flogs  "stat.dat_20220901_235900.txt","stat.dat_20220902_235900.txt",.... in one file "month.txt"

Comment: That is still not a question, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This will create the variable `$txtArray` which will contain the content of all files matching the month 09:

```
$dateString = Get-Date -Month 09 -UFormat '%Y%m'
$txtArray = Get-ChildItem -Filter "stat.dat_*.txt" -Path "C:\Users\**\**\**\**\" | `
Where-Object {$_.Name -match $("stat\.dat_" + $dateString)} | Get-Content
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\**\**\**\**\"` will never go recursively to match files in subfolders like that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all files in that path are from year 2022, you can do something like this:

```
$path = 'C:\Users\somewhere'  # the path where the daily files are

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter "stat.dat_*.txt" -File |
Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match '_\d{8}_\d{6}$' } |                   # filter more fine-tuned
Group-Object {$_.BaseName -replace '.*_\d{4}(\d{2})\d{2}_.*', '$1'} |  # group on just the month part
ForEach-Object {
    # convert the group name to the month name and use for the new file name
    $monthName = (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName([int]$_.Name)
    $monthFile = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ('{0}.txt' -f $monthName)
    # sort the files, get their content and write to the new file
    $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Get-Content | Add-Content -Path $monthFile
}
```

Comment: @oussama_tr Please if my answer solved your problem, let us know. Also, since you're a member of the platform for more than 8 years now, may I ask you to view the [tour] where you can read how to mark a question 'done' by accepting it. So far, you have asked 10 questions but never accepted any of the answers you received..